# how to use async await to prevent getting 0 on array.length of objects?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

What i am doing here is that i am searching in localStorage for some data,Then i am pushing this data(objects) to an array.Later i want to loop this array of objects but the issue is that the length is 0.I know i have to use async await but i dont rly anderstand how it works.

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {

  if (user) {

    this.Uid = user.uid;

    this.storage.get(this.Uid ).then((val) => {

      this.CaloriesChartData = JSON.parse(val);

      if (this.CaloriesChartData != null) {

        this.CaloriesChartData = Object.keys(this.CaloriesChartData).map(key => ({ type: key, value: this.CaloriesChartData[key] }));

        this.CaloriesChartDataLength = this.CaloriesChartData.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.CaloriesChartDataLength; i++) {

          this.CaloriesArray.push(this.CaloriesChartData[i].value);

        }

      }
      console.log(this.CaloriesArray);
      console.log(this.CaloriesArray.length);

    });`
```

And i m getting an [] for the array but it is full when i expand it
and 0 for the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.storage.get(this.Uid )` returns a Promise. A Promise is something that you have to wait for. Therefore, you would need to use `await this.storage.get(this.Uid )`.
But you also want to have the returned value be stored somewhere and not use a Promise chain if you use async await. For example `const data = await this.storage.get(this.Uid )`.
Now you can parse data instead of val.
Since an await can only be used in an async function you have to change your arrow function to be async like:

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(async user => {
```

In total:

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(async user => {

  if (user) {

    this.Uid = user.uid;

    const data = await this.storage.get(this.Uid );

    this.CaloriesChartData = JSON.parse(data);

    if (this.CaloriesChartData != null) {

      ...
```

Comment: So simple yet its exactly what i was looking for.Wish u the best

Comment: glad I could help